# How to filter a stream with a mapped reference of itself?

Tags: java, java-stream

The following code (stripped down to a minimal and hopefully self explanatory example) *feels odd*. I suspect that there is a better way to check for the property than running two full iterations over `states`. May someone give me a hint?

```
public AbstractState getInitialState() {

        List<AbstractState> sourceStates = states
              .stream()
              .map(AbstractState::getTransitions)
              .flatMap(Collection::stream)
              .map(AbstractStateTransition::getFrom)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return states
              .stream()
              .filter(state -> !sourceStates.contains(state))
              .findFirst()
              .orElseThrow(NoInitialStateException::new);
}
```

Comment: Does that code actually achieve what you want it to achieve? You want to determine the initial states? Isn't that normally something that is exactly declared instead of determined based on the transitions?

Comment: Yes, a proper method name should be `findInitialState()`. And yes, its identity should have been known by that time if that was my decision. I have to deal with the chaotic :-(

Answer (score 0):

If it is required to find an initial state, should it imply that such state has all transitions with `from` state set to `null`?

*Assumption: Loops need to be ignored too (when there's a transition with `from` and `to` equal to the current state if applicable).*

If yes, the entire method could be simplified:

```java
public AbstractState findInitialState() {
    return states
          .stream()
          .filter(state -> state.getTransitions().stream()
              .filter(transition -> // remove possible loops where state transits to itself
                  !(state.equals(transition.getFrom()) 
               && state.equals(transition.getTo()))
              )
              .allMatch(transition -> transition.getFrom() == null))
          .findFirst()
          .orElseThrow(NoInitialStateException::new);
}
```